# Method to read a txt file

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new  to C programming and I have some issues with pointer and especially using them as a parameter. What I try to do is reading from a txt file an store the value of it in a variable. My approach was like that:

```
int read_from_file(char path[], char *string){
   //Variables
   char ch;
   char content[32];
   int i=0;

   FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
   if (file != NULL)
           {
               while( ( ch = fgetc(file) ) != EOF ){
                         content[i]=ch;
                         i++;
               }
            printf("File:%s\n", content); //This contains the actual result!
            string = content;   
            fclose(file);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }else{
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *string_1 = (char*) malloc(32*sizeof(char));
    char *string_2 = (char*) malloc(32*sizeof(char));
    char file_path_1[] = "file_1.txt";
    char file_path_2[] = "file_2.txt";

    read_from_file(file_path_1, string_1);
    read_from_file(file_path_2, string_2);

    printf("String 1 :%s\n", string_1);
    printf("String 2 :%s\n", string_2);
}
```

However, the result is the following:

  `File:This is string 1! 
  File:This is string 2!
  Symmetric Key :
  Hash Key      :`
How can I program this method to receive or store the string in a pre defined variable or pointer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: `char ch;` --> `int ch;`

Comment: `string = content` -> [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

Comment: Add `content[i]` = '\0';` before `printf("File:%s\n", content);`.  GTG

Comment: You should make path as a `const char[]` argument. That will allow you to directly call `read_from_file` with string literals as arguments.

Comment: `content[i]=ch;` ->  `string[i]=ch;`, `string = content;` -> `string[i]='\0'` then `printf("File:%s\n", string);`

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed by the standard to be `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of copying the data from `content` to `string` is wrong. You are simply changing the `string` pointer to the value of `content`, but the data that string points to remains unchanged.

The easiest way around this would be to directly store the data to `string`, and drop the temporary variable `content` completely.

If you want to copy data from `content` to `string`, use `memcpy()`.

Also note that there is a function called `fread()`, which can and should be used to read multiple bytes at once.

Also note that, to avoid memory issues, you should always pass the size of the buffer as an argument to your function, to avoid writing or reading behind the end of the buffer.

You should also make sure that your strings are always null-terminated, by storing a `'\0'` after the last character.

Memory management should be one of the primary concerns when programming in `C`. Not knowing precisely what you're doing, or not thinking about it for a few moments, can and will lead to memory issues, which will, in the best case, manifest as a segmentation fault, and in the worst case stay hidden and be exploited for a remote code execution attack against your application. Even programmers with years of `C` experience still make such errors. I thus *strongly* recommend to at least read a few tutorials and articles on how memory works in `C`, how strings work, and what the primary caveats are.
I can also only recommend to activate all compiler warnings using (on `gcc`/`clang`) `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, never ignore the warnings, and regularily run your program through software like `valgrind` to check that it's still error-free.

A few issues of your code:

- `fgetc()` returns an `int`. You are re-interpreting it as a `char`, which causes data loss. Namely, if the input file contains the byte `0xFF`, that will be falesly interpreted as `EOF`.
- If the file is bigger than 32 bytes, your program will write outside of `content`. This leads to undefined behaviour, but most probably, other local variables (`i`, `file`, `ch`) might get overwritten since `content` lies on the stack. The error will most likely be unnoticed at first, but have very ugly, nearly untracable side-effects. If the file is *far* bigger than 32 bytes, the write will be outside the stack, and probably lead to a segmentation fault. Depending on the specifics of your `C` standard library implementation, an attacker could use this bug to manipulate the `file` pointer, which will then cause the next call to `fgetc()` to manipulate an arbitrary place in your program's memory, such as a standard library function pointer. A skilled attacker can hand-craft a specific file that will cause your program to execute arbitrary code.
- If the memory on the stack where `content` lies has other values than `'\0'`, for example because other functions have been called earlier, or if the file size is precisely 32 bytes, then the string that starts at `content[0]` is not properly null-terminated, and `printf` will continue reading the memory until it eventually finds a '\0'. This is also undefined behaviour, but will most probably lead to strange characters being printed, or a segfault. I don't think this bug can be used for any useful attacks, but I might be in error.

Comment: Thank you (actually all of you)! I changed a few things and it's working now! The file I'm reading from is generated by me and the size of is predefined -> It contains random bytes from a GnuPG PRNG.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are obvious intending to return your string via the "char *string" argument. You think that the line:

```
string = content;
```

... should return the string, but all you are doing is overwriting the "string" pointer variable on the stack with the value of the pointer to "content". What you really want to do is to copy the data from the location that "content" points to to the location which "string" points to.

To do this, you should use memcpy(), since you have already allocated the buffer that "string" points to.

Answer (score 0):

in your function, read_from_file(), the buffer content is a local variable. When you do the assignment, string = content, the variable, string gets the address of content...which is on the call stack. When the function returns, that address is likely garbage or invalid.

Instead of doing string = content you need to call memcpy() like this...

```
memcpy(string, content, sizeof content)
```

Comment: hmmm, @MarkBertenshaw answered while I was typing. :)